# ActionMailer debugging

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, actionmailer

I'm trying to use [Action Mailer](http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3) in Rails to send email to users.

```
def create
  ...
  if @post.save
    UserMailer.archive_confirmation(@site).deliver
  end
end
```

But when I try it, I don't get any email, and I have no idea how to debug (since the `create` method runs successfully, and everything else goes as expected, there's no error message) Where could `ActionMailer` go wrong?

Comment: What does your RAILS log say?

Comment: Where can I find my RAILS log?

Comment: Ah found out why. I was trying to assign to a protected variable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your RAILS log, `APP_ROOT/log/development.log` or `APP_ROOT/log/production.log`.

Answer (score 0):

If I am writing the code to sent the email in controller i can write like these to handle the rescue in my application and i can display the error message that is come in rescue we can display.
 I'm using something like this in the controller:

```
if @user.save
  begin
  UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
  flash[:success] = "#{@user.name} created"
  rescue Net::SMTPAuthenticationError, Net::SMTPServerBusy, Net::SMTPSyntaxError, Net::SMTPFatalError, Net::SMTPUnknownError => e
  flash[:notice]=e.message   
  end
  redirect_to home_index_path
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your respective environment file:

```
  ## config/environments/development.rb
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```